# Form is not submitting when "multipart/form-data" was used as the enctype

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, struts2

I have a web form which is having a file upload option. I have used `multipart/form-data` as the enctype and post method to submit the form. At the server-end I'm using struts2 action class. Please find the codes below.

JSP:

```
<s:form action="createAdvertisement" id="heRegistration" theme="simple"
    name="advertisementForm" validate="true" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:hidden name="lastAccessTime" id="lastAccessTime"></s:hidden>

    <table width="520px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
        class="formStyles">
        <tr height="35">
            <td><s:text name="global.Advertisment" /><span
                class="important"> *</span></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="imageUpload"> <span
                id="vMsg"
                style="position: relative; top: -26px; width: 360px; height: 22px; color: red;">
            </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span class="tableErrorSpan"> <s:fielderror
                        cssStyle="font-size:10px;" fieldName="imageUpload"></s:fielderror></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="removeButton"><span id="errAdd" class="tableErrorSpan"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr height="35">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btnIEfix"
                value="<s:text name="button.save"/>"
                name="action:createAdvertisement" alt="Save"> <input
                type="button" name="cancel" class="btn btnIEfix btnInline"
                onclick="location.href='cancelAdvertisement.action'"
                value="<s:text name="button.cancel"/>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

Struts config:

```
<action name="createAdvertisement" method="createAdvertisement"
        class="categoryAdvertisementsAction"> 
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUploadStack" /> 
    <result name="success">jsp/admin/addSuccess.jsp</result> 
    <result name="input">jsp/admin/createAdvertisments.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

Action class code line to accept the input file:

```
private File imageUpload;

final BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(imageUpload);
```

The form is getting submitted in some PCs but it doesn't get submitted in some of the PCs. I need to know why this is happening and whether the enctype is having any dependancies on the hardware.

**Update**

@Konza: Please find the raw html below.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="createAdvertisement.action" name="advertisementForm" id="heRegistration">
  <table width="95%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="formStyles">
      <tbody>
        <tr height="35">
            <td>Advertisement<span class="important"> *</span></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="filestyle-0" style="position: fixed; left: -500px;"><div style="display: inline;" class="bootstrap-filestyle"><input type="text" disabled="" class="input-large"> <label class="btn" for="filestyle-0"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i> <span>Browse</span></label></div>
                    <span style="position: relative; top: -26px; width: 360px; height: 22px; color: red;" id="vMsg">
                    </span>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <span class="tableErrorSpan">
                        </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="removeButton"><span class="tableErrorSpan" id="errAdd"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr height="35">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
            <input type="submit" alt="Save" name="action:createAdvertisement" value="Save" class="btn btnIEfix">
             <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='cancelAdvertisement.action'" class="btn btnIEfix btnInline" name="cancel">
              </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</form>
```

@Andrea Ligios: All the PCs are behind proxy.

@Aleksandr M: Form submission didn't reach the related struts action class as I debug the code using eclipse, so the server-end validations didn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is with different browsers and not with different pc's. Please paste the raw html which is feeding the browser. Take it from the PC in which its not working. :)

Comment: AFAIK it has nothing to do with your system hardware or platform

Comment: some PCs are behind proxy, others are not ? :>

Comment: In some cases validation fails?

Comment: If validations fails action will not be executed.

Comment: 1. Does the form submit after removing the `enctype` attribute ?
2. If yes, then the fileupload validation is failing. I suggest trying with a small file (less than 2MB)